# (maybe NP-Hard) Find total number of subsets of a set such that every subset when multiplied with all its elements has value greater than X

Tags: c++, algorithm

There's an array `arr` of size `n`. So how many of it's `2^n` subsets have a total product greater than a number, say X?

`n` is around 2^5 and X can be bigger around 2^60 (whatever can fit in a C++ `long` variable)

I thought something similar to subset sum would work, but I don't really think so now.

---

I thought about this from [this question from a past contest](http://codeforces.com/contest/799/problem/D) from Codeforces. Though the problem doesn't require what I'm asking, I'm curious.

Comment: If you take the log of all the elements and X, then this becomes the problem of finding how many subsets have sums that exceed some target (since the log of a product is the sum of the logs). This is different from the "subset sum problem" on Wikipedia. But these answers look promising: (1) http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-length-subarray-sum-greater-given-value/ (2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248463/how-many-subsets-of-a-1-2-3-10-have-the-property-that-the-sum-of-their-ele

Comment: Oh... but now won't the numbers be floating points (due to log) - I mean what can I construct the dynamic programming states on? (yeah I too realized the subset sum problem was different to what I thought it meant)

Comment: Yes, but that may not be the end of the world. Do you have code you would use to find the number of subsets that have sums exceeding a target, if the values were all integers?

Comment: If the target is relatively small (around a million) and an integer I think I could construct a dynamic programming solution. `dp[n][sum]` would be the answer, and `dp[i][j]` gives the number of subsets with elements containing only those from `arr[0] .. arr[i]` with sum greater than `j`. So could multiplying logs by a million and rounding them off as integers work?

Comment: I edited this out of my earlier comment, but it might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125393/subset-sum-find-subset-whose-sum-greater-than-k

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your approach, but it sounds like you are able to limit the number of states in the dynamic program based on the fact that the members of `arr` must be integers. That will still be true if they are all logs of integers (whose sums must also be logs of integers). You might be able to make that work by rounding to a certain number of digits. But my instinct is that you would have trouble if the members of `arr` can span a large range -- you will get too many states to deal with anyway.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Yeah now that I think of it, it won't work since many numbers would have the same log value when multiplied with few 10s.

Comment: You might do better posting this on math.stackexchange.com. They may be more prepared to deal with the basic algorithmic question involved (in the second link I posted, they answered a similar question for a specific case).

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43970179/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281798/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75418/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp, for the future, if you're going to suggest another site, it would be nice if you could tell the poster not to cross-post on multiple sites.  You can suggest they flag their question for migration, or (if there are any answers or useful questions) suggest they delete their question here before posting it elsewhere, or just refrain from making the suggestion.  This will lead to a better experience for all.  See my previous comment and the duplication/fragmenting that has happened on multiple sites as a result of this.

Comment: @four_lines the reduction works the other way around. *If* we can solve this problem *then* we can solve the problem with sums instead of products, and *that* problem may be hard (and in fact it is, because if we can solve that problem *then* we can solve the subset sum problem).

Comment: @n.m. What would you say is the complexity of the algorithm in my answer? I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: @m69 if you replace "product" with "sum" in your algorithm description, you get one that solves subset-sum. I don't believe you have proven P=NP, so...

Comment: @n.m. I think the inequality and the multiplication in a limited value space make this much less complex than subset sum, and not NP-hard. But then I'm no expert. It looks like the algorithm is something like N.N.LogN

Comment: @D.W. Sorry about that --I'll be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved by dynamic programming as-is, i.e., without using logs.

When the input integers are given in binary (rather than [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)), 
your problem is NP-hard *under non-adaptive 2-query reductions*, since:

> [number of subsets whose product equals X](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7907/12859)
>   =
>   number of subsets whose product is greater than X-1
>   −
>   number of subsets whose product is greater than X.

I do not immediately see any way of showing actual NP-hardness (i.e., under 1-query reductions).

Comment: I don't want/need to get the number of subsets with product = X, rather no. of subsets with product greater than X.

Comment: That's what I showed is NP-hard under non-adaptive 2-query reductions when the integers are in binary. ​ ​

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain what "non-adaptive 2-query reductions" mean? Thanks

Comment: It means ​ ​ ​ [Turing reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) in which ​ [only 2 queries are made] ​ and ​ [those queries are presented at the same time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-table_reduction) . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

*(In the first version of this answer, I proposed an algorithm that unfortunately contained a logical error; this is a completely reworked version of the answer.)*

As you say, generating all subsets and checking whether their product is greater than X gives a complexity of 2<sup>N</sup>, which is problematic for larger values of N. To get a more efficient method, we'll have to find a way of calculating the number of valid and invalid subsets without actually having to generate them.

Let's take this step by step, using this example:

```
7   2   1   6   3   9   7   5   3   1   (X=240)
```

The number of subsets whose product is greater than X is independent of the order of the integers in the input; so we can start by sorting the input from large to small, without changing the result.

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   2   1   1   (X=240)
```

Adding a 1 to a subset doesn't change its product. Therefore, if there are one or more 1's at the end of the list, we can remove them, and multiply the result from the reduced list by 2<sup>M</sup> (where M is the number of 1's). We now have a list of integers with a reduced N=8 and a minimum value of 2.

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   2   (X=240, M=2)
```

If we iterate over the list from the end, and add every integer to a subset until its product is greater than X, we know the minimum size P for which a random subset is always valid (because we're using the smallest integers).

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   2
                            2 =   2
                        3 x 2 =   6
                    3 x 3 x 2 =  18
                5 x 3 x 3 x 2 =  90
            6 x 5 x 3 x 3 x 2 = 540 > X  ->  P = 5
```

If we add integers to this subset, or replace integers by larger integers, the subset still has a product greater than X. This means that all subsets with at least P integers are valid subsets. There are (N choose P) + (N choose P+1) + ... + (N choose N) of these; in our example with N = 8 and P = 5:

```
 subsets with size 5 = (8 choose 5) = 56  
 subsets with size 6 = (8 choose 6) = 28  
 subsets with size 7 = (8 choose 7) =  8  
 subsets with size 8 = (8 choose 8) =  1  
                                      --
                                      93 subsets
```

*(Note that P is limited by the bit-size of the target X. If X is a 64-bit unsigned integer, then a subset of any 64 integers will always have a product greater than X.)*

If we iterate over the list from the start, and add every integer to a subset while its product is smaller than X, we know the maximum size Q for which a random subset cannot be valid (because we're using the largest integers).

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   2
9                             =   9
9 x 7                         =  63      ->  Q = 2
9 x 7 x 7                     = 441 > X
```

If we remove integers from this subset, or replace integers by smaller integers, the subset still has a product smaller than X. This means that all subsets with at most Q integers are not valid subsets.

So now we know that the subsets sized 1 and 2 are all not valid, the 93 subsets sized 5 to 8 are all valid, and we have to check the subsets sized 3 and 4; we'll check them per size, first 3 and then 4.

To avoid having to generate and check all subsets sized 3, we will divide the selections into groups with a certain number of 0's (non-selected integers) at the end, and calculate the lowest (and highest) possible product, e.g. for the group with three trailing 0's:

```
*   *   *   *   1   0   0   0   <- all possibilities
0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   <- smallest possible product
1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   <- greatest possible product
```

In the example that gives these minimum and maximum products:

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   2   (X=240, SIZE=3)  

*   *   1   0   0   0   0   0   = 441 ~ 441 > X   (2 choose 2) =  1
*   *   *   1   0   0   0   0   = 294 ~ 378 > X   (3 choose 2) =  3
*   *   *   *   1   0   0   0   = 210 ~ 315  
*   *   *   *   *   1   0   0   =  90 ~ 189 < X
*   *   *   *   *   *   1   0   =  45 ~ 189 < X
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   1   =  18 ~ 126 < X
```

We find that the first two groups will always have a product greater than X (and we only need to calculate the minimum product to know this), so we calculate their number and add it to the total. For the groups whose minimum value is lower than X, we also calculate the maximum value, and we find that the three last groups always have a product that is smaller than X, so we can ignore them.

*(As soon as you find a group whose maximum value is lower that X, you can skip checking the next groups, because their maximum value will never be greater.)*

That leaves us with the group with three trailing 0's. To check how many of the subsets in this group are valid, we select the lowest integer (5), decrement the subset size, and recurse:

```
9   7   7   6   (product * 5 > X=240, SIZE=2)  

*   1   0   0   = 63 ~ 63 * 5 > X    (1 choose 1) = 1
*   *   1   0   = 49 ~ 63 * 5 > X    (2 choose 1) = 2
*   *   *   1   = 42 ~ 54 * 5
```

We find that the first two groups are always valid, but the product of the third group can be smaller or greater than X. So we select the lowest integer (6), decrement the subset size, and recurse:

```
9   7   7   (product * 5 * 6 > X=240, Size=1)

1   0   0   = 9 * 30 > X    (0 choose 0) = 1  
*   1   0   = 7 * 30 < X  
*   *   1   = 7 * 30 < X
```

We find that only the first group is always valid, so we calculate its number (this is the lowest recursion level, so this is 1) and add it to the total. So we have found that the number of valid subsets sized 3 is 8. We then go on to do the same for subsets sized 4:

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   2   (X=240, SIZE=4)  

*   *   *   1   0   0   0   0   = 2646 ~ 2646 > X    (3 choose 3) =  1
*   *   *   *   1   0   0   0   = 1470 ~ 2205 > X    (4 choose 3) =  4
*   *   *   *   *   1   0   0   =  630 ~ 1323 > X    (5 choose 3) = 10
*   *   *   *   *   *   1   0   =  270 ~ 1323 > X    (6 choose 3) = 20
*   *   *   *   *   *   *   1   =   90 ~  882
```

We recurse for the last group:

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   3   (product * 2 > X=240, SIZE=3)  

*   *   1   0   0   0   0   = 441 ~ 441 * 2 > X    (2 choose 2) = 1
*   *   *   1   0   0   0   = 294 ~ 378 * 2 > X    (3 choose 2) = 3
*   *   *   *   1   0   0   = 210 ~ 315 * 2 > X    (4 choose 2) = 6
*   *   *   *   *   1   0   =  90 ~ 189 * 2 
*   *   *   *   *   *   1   =  45 ~ 189 * 2
```

We recurse for the penultimate group:

```
9   7   7   6   5   (product * 2 * 3 > X=240, SIZE=2)  

*   1   0   0   0   = 63 ~ 63 * 6 > X    (1 choose 1) = 1
*   *   1   0   0   = 49 ~ 63 * 6 > X    (2 choose 1) = 2
*   *   *   1   0   = 42 ~ 54 * 6 > X    (3 choose 1) = 3
*   *   *   *   1   = 30 ~ 45 * 6
```

We recurse for the last group:

```
9   7   7   6   (product * 2 * 3 * 5 > X=240, SIZE=1)  

1   0   0   0   = 9 * 30 > X    (0 choose 0) = 1
*   1   0   0   = 7 * 30 < X
*   *   1   0   = 7 * 30 < X
*   *   *   1   = 6 * 30 < X
```

We go back up one step and recurse for the last group:

```
9   7   7   6   5   3   (product * 2 * 3 > X=240, SIZE=2)  

*   1   0   0   0   0   = 63 ~ 63 * 6 > X    (1 choose 1) = 1
*   *   1   0   0   0   = 49 ~ 63 * 6 > X    (2 choose 1) = 2
*   *   *   1   0   0   = 42 ~ 54 * 6 > X    (3 choose 1) = 3
*   *   *   *   1   0   = 30 ~ 45 * 6
*   *   *   *   *   1   = 15 ~ 27 * 6 < X
```

We recurse for the penultimate group:

```
9   7   7   6   (product * 2 * 3 * 5 > X=240, SIZE=1)  

1   0   0   0   0   = 9 * 30 > X    (0 choose 0) = 1
*   1   0   0   0   = 7 * 30 < X
*   *   1   0   0   = 7 * 30 < X
*   *   *   1   0   = 6 * 30 < X
```

So for subsets sized 4 we find a total of 59 valid subsets; this gives:

```
 subsets with size 5 ~ 8 =  93
 subsets with size 4     =  59 
 subsets with size 3     =   8
                           ---
                           160
```

Because we removed two 1's at the start, we have to multiply this with 2<sup>2</sup>, for a total of:

```
160 * 2^2 = 640
```

valid subsets out of a total of 2^10 = 1024 subsets. To get to this result, we have calculated the product of around 50 subsets.

*As you can see from the example, there are some calculations of subset products which are repeated in several recursions. This means that dynamic programming techniques such as memoization could speed up the algorithm considerably.*

---

COMPLEXITY AND WORST CASE

The sorting of the input takes O(N.LogN), followed by a few steps which each take O(N).

For the last step, the worst case input is of course if you can create a valid subset with 1 integer, and an invalid subset with N-1 integers, e.g. if the list contains a large number of small integers and one big integer greater than the target X; that means you have to check all the subset sizes in detail.

The last step is difficult to quantise; a worst case would be at least O(N<sup>2</sup>), but then the recursion depth comes into play. I guess a list with a lot of duplicate values would create a lot of overlapping ranges and a lot of recursions, and a complexity of O(N<sup>3</sup>).

It seems obvious to see this last step as the most complex, and therefore to put the overall complexity at O(N<sup>3</sup>), but because subsets sized 64 or greater are always valid (for a 64-bit value of X), there is a limit to how much the complexity of the last step can grow, and for large values of N, the sorting at the beginning of the algorithm may become the dominant factor.

Comment: Could you explain on your update? Also n is less than or equal to 32, so that's fine

Comment: @four_lines I've reworked the answer with the other sorting direction, which makes more sense.

Comment: Oh this makes sense, nice! I'm wondering what the worst case complexity is... I think it's probably for some set that goes `{10^18,2,2,...2}`

Comment: @four_lines I added a paragraph about the complexity and the worst case input.

Comment: @four_lines I just realised the algorithm contains a fatal flaw; I've updated the question to explain the error. You should probably unaccept the answer; you can always give me an upvote for effort instead :-)

Comment: If you get to e.g. `subsetProduct(000100011) >= X`, you can say picking one element from the left-most 4 and then 2 elements from the remaining 8 will result in a sum >= X. Then you need to calculate how many `subsetProduct(0000????? with 3 1's) >= X`. Then do the same for 2 1's and 1 1. This idea could be used to "fix" this algorithm, but that would probably make it exponential.